# Hive table on delta lake

Tags: apache-spark, hive, delta-lake

I am new to spark & delta lake. I am creating hive table on top of delta table. I have necessary jars delta-core-shaded-assembly_2.11-0.1.0.jar, hive-delta_2.11-0.1.0.jar; in hive class path. Set following properties.

```
SET hive.input.format=io.delta.hive.HiveInputFormat;
SET hive.tez.input.format=io.delta.hive.HiveInputFormat;
```

But while creating table

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hive_table(col1 INT, col2 STRING)
STORED BY 'io.delta.hive.DeltaStorageHandler'
LOCATION '/path/to/my/delta/table'`

Getting following exception:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
>   org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.byteStringAs(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/spark/network/util/ByteUnit;)J

Schema of both table matches. Stack details:
Spark: 2.4.4
Hive: 1.2.1

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hive with delta lake only supporting with spark 3.0 and delta version 0.7.0.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
  <artifactId>delta-core_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```